# PHP Reflection class newInstance exit on execution

Tags: php, reflection, fuelphp

I'm writing controller testing unit with Fuelphp framework. And inside the code I'm trying to request application controller like this one :

```
$response = Request::force('controller_name/controller_method')->set_method('GET')->execute();
```

But this code unexpectedly exits the entire testing unit like PHP exit function. After trying to figure out what happened inside the core source code, I found out that in [line 440](https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.9/develop/classes/request.php#L440) of https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.9/develop/classes/request.php forces the program to exit without any exception.

```
$this->controller_instance = $class->newInstance($this);
```

And before this code

```
$class = new \ReflectionClass($this->controller)
```

I'm using PHP 5.6.33 and Fuelphp 1.7.2 in my machine and I hope someone can help me with this error.

Comment: In general, from my experience with FuelPHP, it's a. unstable; b. untestable. Since the framework is based on singleton pattern with tons of static calls, doing unit tests on that is painful. My solution - I fired the client. Your solution? Your problem is somewhere else. `ReflectionClass` always throws  `ReflectionException` if problems occur. So keep looking.

Comment: I also thought that `ReflectionClass` will throw some kind of exception. But after I test the try-catch and var_dump the exception, it catch no exception, just exit unexpectedly. It is written in the docs that the `ReflectionException` will only occur if the constructor is not public, or the class doesn't have a constructor or the parameter contains one or more parameters. What will happened if I pass the wrong parameter format in the `ReflectionClass`? Will it also throws the `ReflectionException`?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a typo in your question but to be sure : you said

```
Request::force
```

instead of

```
Request::forge
```

Anyway, I have a lot of tests wrote in the same way but we add few lines before calling forge it :

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1';
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = 'application/json'; // this one may not be required for you
$_POST = array();
$_GET = array();
$request = \Request::forge('controller/action')->set_method('GET');
$request->execute();
```